# jQuery .animate goes wrong direction why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Here is my CSS:

```
.animate-rectangle {
    background-color:#0F0;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

And the jQuery codes:

```
<!--Jquery Code to Animate Rectangle from Left to Right-->
$(document).ready(function () {

    var windo_width = $(document).width() - 300;

    $("#reset").click(function () {
        $(".animate-rectangle").animate({
            "left": "100px"
        }, "slow");
    });

    $("#MoveRight").click(function () {
        $(".animate-rectangle").animate({
            "left": "+=" + windo_width
        }, "slow");
    });

});
```

Look at jQuery codes it declares that `animate({"left":"100px"}` but in action it goes right why this happend?

Comment: Format your code, before posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

While looking at your `css`, you dont assigned a `left` for the element initially. So it will take its `left` as `0` by default. So now you are trying to `animate` the left to `100`, obviously your element will moves right in order move from `0 to 100`. Try to set an initial left position for your element.

```
  ***    ------>         ***
  ***                    *** 
  |                      |
  |                      |
  left : 0               left: 100
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with the `left` position of the `.animate-rectangle` will be `0`, or the `left` value of it's closest relative parent. The animation moves it to the right because a value of `100` is greater than it's origin point. If you want to move it `100px` to the right relative to where it starts, use `+=100px`:

```
$("#reset").click(function () {
    $(".animate-rectangle").animate({
        "left": "+=100px"
    }, "slow");
});
```